# How to get the expected output with Java 8 features?

Tags: java-8

**For the below input:**

INPUT1 = "0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00||0.10";

INPUT2 = "404,671.00|0.00|0.00|417,975.64|0.00|0.00|417,353.81|0.00|0.00|418,338.38|0.00|0.00|418,908.39||";

INPUT3 = "404,671.00|0.00|0.00|417,975.64|0.00|0.00|417,353.81|0.00|0.00|418,338.38|0.00|0.00|418,908.39";

INPUT4 = "20,500,000.00|20,500,000.00|20,500,000.00|20,500,000.00|20,500,000.00|20,500,000.00|20,500,000.00|20,500,000.00|20,500,000.00";

INPUT5 = "20181221|20181227|20190128|20190227|20190327|20190429|20190528|20190627|20190729|20190827|20190927|20191028|20191127|20191227|20200127|20200227";

**Output Should be like below:**

*#No|input5|input4|input2|input1|input3*

- 1|20181221|20,500,000.00|404,671.00|0.00|404,671.00
- 2|20181227|20,500,000.00|0.00|0.00|0.00

.......

Tried in traditional (old way). But, implementation should be in Java 8.

```
public class FormatterDemo {
    public static String INPUT1 = "0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00||0.10";
    public static String INPUT2 = "404,671.00|0.00|0.00|417,975.64|0.00|0.00|417,353.81|0.00|0.00|418,338.38|0.00|0.00|418,908.39||";
    public static String INPUT3 = "404,671.00|0.00|0.00|417,975.64|0.00|0.00|417,353.81|0.00|0.00|418,338.38|0.00|0.00|418,908.39";
    public static String INPUT4 = "20,500,000.00|20,500,000.00|20,500,000.00|20,500,000.00|20,500,000.00|20,500,000.00|20,500,000.00|20,500,000.00|20,500,000.00";
    public static String INPUT5 = "20181221|20181227|20190128|20190227|20190327|20190429|20190528|20190627|20190729|20190827|20190927|20191028|20191127|20191227|20200127|20200227";
    public static String REGEX_PATTERN = "\\|";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] input1SplitStr = INPUT1.split(REGEX_PATTERN);
        String[] input2SplitStr = INPUT2.split(REGEX_PATTERN);
        String[] input3SplitStr = INPUT3.split(REGEX_PATTERN);
        String[] input4SplitStr = INPUT4.split(REGEX_PATTERN);
        String[] input5SplitStr = INPUT5.split(REGEX_PATTERN);

        int maxSizeValue = findMaxValue(input1SplitStr.length, input2SplitStr.length, input3SplitStr.length,
                input4SplitStr.length, input5SplitStr.length);

        for (int i = 1; i <= maxSizeValue; i++) {
            String input5Value = (i <= input5SplitStr.length && input5SplitStr[i - 1] != null)
                    ? input5SplitStr[i - 1]
                    : "";
            String input4Value = (i <= input4SplitStr.length && input4SplitStr[i - 1] != null)
                    ? input4SplitStr[i - 1]
                    : "";
            String input2Value = (i <= input2SplitStr.length && input2SplitStr[i - 1] != null)
                    ? input2SplitStr[i - 1]
                    : " ";
            String input1Value = (i <= input1SplitStr.length && input1SplitStr[i - 1] != null)
                    ? input1SplitStr[i - 1]
                    : " ";

            String input3Value = (i <= input3SplitStr.length && input3SplitStr[i - 1] != null)
                    ? input3SplitStr[i - 1]
                    : " ";

            System.out.println(i + "|" + input5Value + "|" + input4Value + "|" + input2Value + "|" + input1Value
                    + "|" + input3Value);
        }
    }

    private static int findMaxValue(int... lengths) {
        int maxLength = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i : lengths) {
            if (i > maxLength) {
                maxLength = i;
            }
        }
        return maxLength;
    }
}
```

**Expected/current output:**

**No|input5|input4|input2|input1|input3**

- 1|20181221|20,500,000.00|404,671.00|0.00|404,671.00
- 2|20181227|20,500,000.00|0.00|0.00|0.00
- 3|20190128|20,500,000.00|0.00|0.00|0.00
- 4|20190227|20,500,000.00|417,975.64|0.00|417,975.64
- 5|20190327|20,500,000.00|0.00|0.00|0.00 .

.........

This is the traditional way I implemented.
Help would be appreciated to do in java 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it could be smth. like this one:

```
List<String[]> data = Stream.of(INPUT5, INPUT4, INPUT3, INPUT2, INPUT1)
                            .map(in -> in.split(REGEX_PATTERN))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

IntSupplier getMaxLength = () -> data.stream().mapToInt(arr -> arr.length).max().orElse(0);
BiFunction<String[], Integer, String> valueAt = (arr, i) -> Optional.ofNullable(i < arr.length ? arr[i] : null).orElse("");

List<String> lines = IntStream.range(0, getMaxLength.getAsInt())
                              .mapToObj(i -> {
                                  Stream<String> s1 = Stream.of(String.valueOf(i + 1));
                                  Stream<String> s2 = data.stream().map(arr -> valueAt.apply(arr, i));
                                  return Stream.concat(s1, s2).collect(Collectors.joining("|"));
                              }).collect(Collectors.toList());

lines.forEach(System.out::println);
```